# gdb output starts threads but gives on output

Tags: c++, macos, gdb

I have some code that segfaults after giving a few lines of output. But when I run the code on gdb like so:

`(gdb) r < err.in`

I get the following

```
Starting program: /Users/prikshetsharma/Downloads/parser/parse < err.in                                                                   
[New Thread 0xf03 of process 39241]                                                                                             
[New Thread 0xc03 of process 39241]
```

And gdb just keeps stuck here. And it doesn't give the output it gives while running it regularly. How to fix this?

-- Edit --

An interesting thing is happening. Sometimes gdb gives the output and sometimes it doesn't, even though I change nothing. When it does give an output it does the following:

```
Starting program: /Users/prikshetsharma/Downloads/parser/parse < err.in                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[New Thread 0x1003 of process 39841]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[New Thread 0x1103 of process 39841]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[New Thread 0x1503 of process 39841]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/bsd.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                               
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/darwin_vers.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                       
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/dirstat.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                           
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/dirstat_collection.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/err.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                               
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/exception.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                         
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/init.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                              
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/mach.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                              
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/stdio.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                             
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/stdlib.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                            
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/string.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                            
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/variant.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
```

followed by the regular output of the program. That's strange.

Comment: dumb question, was it compiled with -g? also, it might be (wait for it) a stack overflow or call-stack breach before entering main(), it may cause backtrace to fail.

Comment: press a ctrl-c, and check out with `bt` what the program does.

Comment: We would need a minimal reproducing example to say, as well as possibly more output.  There isn't enough information in the answer as given to say.

Comment: I am having a similar type of problem in Visual Studio on Mac OX. Gdb writes "[New Thread 0xf03 of process 4485]" and then gets stuck there. If I rerun it several times, then it starts to work. Could you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Really, I have no idea what could be here `can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.`
Looks like they are default objectives and, maybe, rebuilding and re-linking Your's sources could help.

But I have found some sort of workaround to trick this thing sticking on `New Thread`.

***0-2 is a basic preparation from scratch ***

1. `echo "set startup-with-shell off" >> ~/.gdbinit`
2. Make sure that your*s gdb is codesigned, Darwin requires it.
3. Compile code with `-g` option
4. Run Your gdb
5. Load symbols by `file "your app name"`
6. Set a breakpoint, for example, on  `main` by executing `b main`
7. Run your program by executing `run` in gdb.
8. Happy debugging.

Link for codesigning: https://superuser.com/questions/1436370/how-to-codesign-gdb-on-os-x-mojave

**Note:**

```
My gdb is updated to the `9.1_1` version and codesigned. 

MacOS version: Catalina(10.15.4)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem generally happens when gdb can not open object file to run the program. One way to fix this -

1. Start the gdb with the object file `gdb <executable for example a.out>`
2. This will invoke gdb prompt. Then, set break point on gdb prompt `b <function name for example b main>`
3. Then `run <executable for example run a.out>`

This should start the gdb running the program in debug mode and one can step through and use gdb as needed.

Answer (score -1):

> And gdb just keeps stuck here.

Most likely cause: your program has a bug (we already know it does, since it crashes), and deadlocks when running under GDB (not unexpected: GDB can affect timing of threads).

> How to fix this?

Use Control-C to interrupt your program, find out *where* it is deadlocked, fix the bug.

Comment: ```Control-C``` isn't interrupting the program for some reason.